# Can anyone suggest how to implement the sorting by price of a product in android Recycler View

Tags: android, sorting, comparable

As I needed to sort the values of an array List, I'm unable to get the sorting algorithms for the different algorithms like Selection sort, quick sort and bubble sort. I'm new to Android app development, please help me to solve this. thanks in advance

```
public class TestingSort {
public static void main(String args[]){

        ToSort toSort1 = new ToSort(new Float(3), "3");
        ToSort toSort2 = new ToSort(new Float(6), "6");
        ToSort toSort3 = new ToSort(new Float(9), "9");
        ToSort toSort4 = new ToSort(new Float(1), "1");
        ToSort toSort5 = new ToSort(new Float(5), "5");
        ToSort toSort6 = new ToSort(new Float(0), "0");
        ToSort toSort7 = new ToSort(new Float(3), "3");
        ToSort toSort8 = new ToSort(new Float(-3), "-3");

        List<ToSort> sortList = new ArrayList<ToSort>();
        sortList.add(toSort1);
        sortList.add(toSort2);
        sortList.add(toSort3);
        sortList.add(toSort4);
        sortList.add(toSort5);
        sortList.add(toSort6);
        sortList.add(toSort7);
        sortList.add(toSort8);

        Collections.sort(sortList);

        for(ToSort toSort : sortList){
            System.out.println(toSort.toString());
        }
    }

}

     public class ToSort implements Comparable<ToSort> {

    private Float val;
    private String id;

    public ToSort(Float val, String id){
        this.val = val;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ToSort f) {

        if (val.floatValue() > f.val.floatValue()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (val.floatValue() <  f.val.floatValue()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Comparator` with `Collections.sort()`

```
Collections.sort(YourArraylist, new Comparator<ModelObject>(){
   public int compare(ModelObject o1, ModelObject o2){
      return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
   }
});
```

If you are using Java 8, You can use following code.

```
Collections.sort(YourArraylist, (o1, o2) -> o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice());
```